# Is n O(n)? Is n Ω(n)?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I have a homework assignment (though this isn't part of it!) which I want to be sure on. This may be a stupid question.

The functions in question are $f(n) = 2^n$ and $g(n) = 3^n$. I'm pretty sure about the following:

$f$ is $O(g)$ as $2^n \leq 3^n \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$, using $c = 1$.

$f$ is also $\Omega(g)$. Proof:

$f$ being $\Omega(g)$ means that for some $c > 0$ we have that $c \cdot 2^n \geq 3^n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Taking $log_3$ of both sides gives us $\log_3(c \cdot 2^n) \geq n$.

We can use change-of-base to get: $\frac{\log_2(c \cdot 2^n)}{\log_2(3)} \geq n$.

Log rules give us $\frac{\log_2(c)}{\log_2(3)} + \frac{n}{\log_2(3)} \geq n$.

This shows that $f$ is $\Omega(g)$ if $n$ is $\Omega(n)$, with some $c$ equal to $\frac{1}{log_2(3)}$.

If there are any problems, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't switch the inequality sign when taking logs....

Comment: @mathworker21 you're right - changed

Comment: Your last inequality implies this is only true for $n\le\frac{\log_2c}{\log_23-1}=k$, so whatever value of $c$ you chose, it will not be true for $n>k$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri could you explain that further, please?

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks. Realized that that wasn't the main problem (and deleted the comment). But now that is the problem.

Comment: You want to prove that for some $c>0,c2^n\ge3^n$ for all $n\ge n_0$. On solving the inequality, you get that this is only true for $n\le k$, so your hypothesis is not true for any $n>k$. So $2^n\notin\Omega(3^n)$

Comment: @FibroMyAlgebra $\log f\in \Omega(\log g)$ does not imply $f\in\Omega(g)$, as mathworker21 implied in his comment.

Comment: @mathworker21 where am I implying this?

Comment: @DirkGently I don't think he is assuming this. He is just taking logarithms of the concrete inequality $c 2^n \ge 3^n$. Nowhere does he have $c (n \log 2) \ge n \log 3$.

Comment: @DirkGently I think $\log$ is only being taken to solve the inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly (as far as I can see from a quick read) rewritten the condition to
$$\frac{\log_2(c)}{\log_2(3)} + \frac{n}{\log_2(3)} \geq n$$
But then you need to argue that you can make this true *for all sufficiently large $n$* just by choosing $c$ right -- and that is *not* the case.

The factor $\frac{1}{\log_2 3}$ is less than $1$, so the difference between the two terms involving $n$ *gets ever larger* the larger $n$ is. Therefore, no matter what you take $c$ to be, this difference will eventually be more than the constant $\frac{\log_2c}{\log_23}$, and therefore your rewritten inequality *does not hold* for all large enough $n$ -- also no matter what you take "large enough" to mean.

Comment: There we go. Thanks! I really appreciate the help. I'm pretty new to the wonderful world of asymptotics.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach: $$\frac{c 2^n}{3^n} \to 0$$ no matter what $c$ is, so $2^n$ is not $\Omega(3^n)$.

---

Using your approach:
Because $\log_2(3) > 1$ we will always have $\frac{\log_2(c)}{\log_2(3)} + \frac{n}{\log_2(3)} \le n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, no matter what $c$ is.

Comment: he's probably asking what the flaw in his logic is

Comment: Yes. Could you explain further?

Comment: @angryavian Sorry, did I mess up my ineq signs or did you mess up yours? I think you mean $\geq$ there as $f = Ω(g)$ means: $\exists c > 0$, $n_0 \geq 0$ such that $g(n) \leq cf(n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: @FibroMyAlgebra From your work, you showed that you want to find a $c$ such that $\frac{\log_2(c)}{\log_2(3)} + \frac{n}{\log_2(3)} \ge n$ for all large $n$. In my answer I note that this is impossible, since the left-hand side is a line (as a function of $n$ with a smaller slope than the slope of the right-hand side.

Comment: Ah, I see. @henningmakholm also answered this. Thanks!